# An error occurred while loading navigation: Attempted to use Snappy compression, but Snappy is not installed

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I was tryign to install the latest mongo database on my MacOS via the [official tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/). So the following commands effectively seem to work for me:

```
brew services start mongodb-community@4.4
brew services list
```

lists the following

```
mongodb-community started naman .../LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
```

Further, when I am trying to execute `mongo`, I am able to successfully create a session for shell

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.3 
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb 
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("57e62dd9-77f2-48c2-8fe8-8fe9fe79a1d2") }
```

and access the databases, collections, execute the queries, and all.

But further trying to connect to this URI using MongoDB Compass to make use of its [visual tree for `explain`](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/query-plan#std-label-explain-plans), I am getting to see that the compression has to be enabled as a must:

[image]

and upon specifying the compression as `snappy`, it would read the following:

> An error occurred while loading navigation: Attempted to use Snappy
> compression, but Snappy is not installed. Install or disable Snappy
> compression and try again.

The MongoDB Version in use is `v4.4.3` and compass version `Version 1.25.0`, is there a workaround for this or do I need to tweak my configs from defaults?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since here described in [urioption.compressors](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/index.html#urioption.compressors):

> Comma-delimited string of compressors to enable network compression for communication between this client and a mongod/mongos instance.
>
> You can specify the following compressors:
>
> - snappy
> - zlib (Available in MongoDB 3.6 or greater)
> - zstd (Available in MongoDB 4.2 or greater)

---

Why `compressors=disabled` is working in  mongo-shell(mongo) and not in mongo-compass?

> *Value for `compressors` must be at least one of: `snappy`, `zlib`*

So here,

1. [net.compression.compressors](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/index.html#net.compression.compressors), [cmdoption-mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/index.html#cmdoption-mongod-networkmessagecompressors), [cmdoption-mongos](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongos/#cmdoption-mongos-networkmessagecompressors),

   - they have specified

> *To disable network compression, set the value to disabled.*

2. [compression-options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#compression-options) in Connection String URI Format and [cmdoption-mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-mongo-networkmessagecompressors),

   - They have not specified any validation like first point

As per above points might be it is required in mongo-compass and not in mongo-shell! For detailed and specific answer you can ask to [MongoDB community Forum](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/) or post a bug in [MongoDB Jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/plugins/servlet/samlsso),

---

and upon specifying the compression as snappy, it would read the following:

> An error occurred while loading navigation: Attempted to use Snappy compression, but `Snappy` is not installed. Install or disable Snappy compression and try again.

See here [term-snappy](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-snappy),

> A compression/decompression library designed to balance efficient computation requirements with reasonable compression rates. [Snappy](https://google.github.io/snappy/) is the default compression library for MongoDB’s use of WiredTiger. See Snappy and the WiredTiger compression documentation for more information.

You need to install it separately if you want to use Snappy.

**Conclusion:**

You can use [zlib](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-zlib) instead of Snappy, or more better if you don't specify `compressors=disabled` or `compressors=zlib` because by default it will specify `compressors=snappy,zstd,zlib` all 3 options when you don't specify in uri.

Comment: `zlib` works and even getting rid of everything after the port in the URL works (y)

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the "compression" query option entirely and it still works like so
`mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb`